# pivot not working as desired

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

i have records as below

```
txn_date        remarks
11/1/2013   bank
11/1/2013   bank
11/1/2013   bank
11/2/2013   bank
11/2/2013   remit
11/3/2013   bank
```

I need to show the records as below

```
date             remit   bank
11/1/2013        0       3
11/2/2013        1       1
11/3/2013        0       1
```

and so on

i tried

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    select txn_date,
case when remarks is NULL then 'bank' else remarks  end as remarks
 from nibl

) as s
PIVOT
(
    count(txn_date)
    FOR [remarks] IN (remit,bank)
)AS p
```

but it gave result as below

```
remit       bank 
35201   32595
```

i need count of remit and bank for each date. what is the solution?

Comment: There's no 'remarks' column in source data!

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a cleaner way to do it than to add an extra dummy column:

```
declare @t table (txn_date date,remarks varchar(5))
insert into @t(txn_date,remarks) values
('20131101','bank'),
('20131101','bank'),
('20131101','bank'),
('20131102','bank'),
('20131102','remit'),
('20131103','bank')

;With added as (
    select txn_date,remarks,1 as cnt
    from @t
)
select txn_date,bank,remit
from added pivot (COUNT(cnt) for remarks in (bank,remit)) t
```

When you have a pivot clause that looks like this:

```
pivot (COUNT(columnA) for columnB in (...))
```

neither `columnA` not `columnB` will exist in the result set that the `pivot` produces. As such, since we want `txn_date` to survive, it can't be one of those columns. Unfortunately, there has to be some column named in `COUNT()`, you can't just do `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(1)`, so I had to add an extra column.

Result:

```
txn_date   bank        remit
---------- ----------- -----------
2013-11-01 3           0
2013-11-02 1           1
2013-11-03 1           0
```

Answer (score 1):

I simply changed your count(txn_date) to count(remarks):

```
declare @t1 table  (txn_date date, remarks varchar(8))

insert into @t1 values 
('11/1/2013', 'bank')
,('11/1/2013', 'bank')
,('11/1/2013', 'bank')
,('11/2/2013', 'bank')
,('11/2/2013', 'remit')
,('11/3/2013', 'bank')


SELECT *
FROM (
    select txn_date,
case when remarks is NULL then 'bank' else remarks  end as remarks
 from @t1 

) as s
PIVOT
(
    count([remarks])
    FOR [remarks] IN (remit,bank)
)AS p
```